# How can I restrict/prevent .net code execution on internet?

Tags: .net, class-library, cas

I develop a series of .NET class libraries and I don't want them to run from a web site. That is, users could only use/call my libraries through windows desktop applications. For example I don't want the users to be able to use these libraries in an ASP.NET web application, on a web site. Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: Why are you trying to do this?

Comment: @SLaks: There could be many good reasons. For example, you have a license agreement that information will not be available on the web, and the library in question is how the information is going to be accessed.

Comment: @Yuriy: If so, he should give up.  It is _completely impossible_ to enforce that.  Remember about Reflector / Reflexil and about virtual server farms (each VM running a copy of the app and a WCF service called by ASP.Net)

Comment: Thank you all. Yes, Yuiry, licensing issues are involved. However, I'd like to refresh my question: is there a way to enforce execution only from a specific web site (e.g. www.somedomain.com)?

Comment: No, somebody could still decompile your library and remove whatever protections you put in place. And if you were to run it from that website, somebody could just make calls to that website for their own site.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can prevent your code from running in a server-side ASP.Net AppDomain by checking whether `HttpRuntime.AppDomainAppVirtualPath` is not `null` and throwing an exception.

However, that won't stop someone from running your app in a separate AppDomain from ASP.Net, and it certainly won't stop someone from runnng the app as a service and exposing it to ASP.Net using WCF or named pipes.

Why are you trying to do this?

**EDIT**: To answer your comment, that's also impossible to do perfectly.
You could check the HOST header, and someone could defeat it using `SimpleWorkerRequest`.
In addition, anything can be beaten by editing the assembly.  (No obfuscator is perfect)

Answer (score 4):

No. Even if you were to stop your library from running under IIS, somebody could still run a desktop app with your library, and communicate with it from IIS.

Comment: ...and Citrix or similar technologies also allow users to run the app remotely.

Answer (score 1):

No, not really.

However, depending on what your application is you may be able to cripple it's application for use online. If you use named mutexes you can ensure only 1 operation ever starts at any one time. Similar to starting 1 instance of a desktop application, you ensure that all calls to DoWork() for example are sequential.

This means that using the web, they couldn't make repeated calls. But it does depend on how you envisage it's use in a desktop app.

Answer (score 0):

Just as the other solutions not very safe, but you could check if a message loop is running using [Application.MessageLoop](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.application.messageloop.aspx) which should typically be true for WinForms applications but not for web applications.

Comment: And I could beat that by making a new thread, calling `Application.Run` with an invisible form, and `Invoke` ing library calls onto the form.